# How to replace blank column values with some default value in Spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some fields in my data having blank values and I want to replace those values with the default values as "NA".

Input Records:

```
+-------+--------------------------+
|name   |email                     |
+-------+--------------------------+
|Bob    |Bob@gmail.com             |
|Tom    |                          |
+-------+--------------------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+-------+--------------------------+
|name   |email                     |
+-------+--------------------------+
|Bob    |aditya@gmail.com          |
|Tom    |NA                        |
+-------+--------------------------+
```

What I did was trying to use coalesce to replace the blank values with NA, but it's not working as expected.

spark.sql("""select name, coalesce(email, "Not Available") as email from temp""").show(false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), the coalesce function *"Returns the first column that is not null, or null if all inputs are null"*.

With only one column, it will simply always return the value of that column. Also, a blank value is not a null value. In other words, `null != ""`.

One way to solve your problem would be to use the `when` function as follows:

```scala
df.withColumn("email", when('email === "", "NA").otherwise('email)
```

In SQL, it could look like this:

```scala
spark.sql("select case when email = '' then 'NA' else email end from temp")
```

Answer (score 2):

Coalesce will only work if there are null values, and **Empty whitespace** not treated as **null**.

**To resolve your issue:**

**`1.Using length & trim functions:`**

```
df.withColumn("email", when((length(trim('email)) === 0 ), lit("NA"))
      .otherwise('email))
  .show(false)
```

**`2.Using regexp_replace:`**

```
df.select('name,regexp_replace('email, "^\\s+$", "NA"))
.show(false)
```